# Vanity Url, reading an entered string instead of int

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, actionresult

I'm trying to allow for Vanity Urls, but I am running into the problem that if I enter

```
XXXX/User/Profile/Test
```

instead of

```
xxxx/User/Profile/224
```

That it cannot read the string.

My current ActionResult is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Profile(int ID = -1, string VanityID = null)
    {
        if (VanityID == null)
        {
            ppUser viewerChoice = DB.ppUser_GetUserByPersonID(ID);
            return View(viewerChoice);
        }
        else
        {
            ppUser viewerChoice = DB.ppUser_GetUserByVanityID(VanityID);
            return View(viewerChoice);
        }
    }
```

It will take in int Id if an int is entered into the URL, but if a string is entered nothing is taken in and it throws an error because the ID is read as being -1.

I have also been trying to use 2 Action Results as follows:

```
public ActionResult Profile(int ID)
    {
            ppUser viewerChoice = DB.ppUser_GetUserByPersonID(ID);
            return View(viewerChoice);
    }

    public ActionResult Profile(string ID)
    {
        ppUser viewerChoice = DB.ppUser_GetUserByVanityID(ID);
        return View(viewerChoice);
    }
```

But it is throwing an AmbiguousMatchException error at me when i try to call either ActionResult.

This is the routes.Maproute if it helps at all as well.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new { controller = @"[^\.]*" }, // Parameter constraints
            new string[] { typeof(MvcApplication).Namespace + ".Controllers" }
        );
```

Comment: I would suggest that you create two seperate routes (with constraints). One that accepts {id} and validates that it is an integer and a second that takes {name} and validates that it is a string. Then your section action would be string Name not string ID.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're nearly there. Try [setting a constraint](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx) for the id:

```
new { ID = @"\d+" }
```

This will guarantee that, if you try to access XXXX/User/Profile/Test, your action won't be hit because Test is not really an id.